# How to validate dynamic API response (Schema validation) in Postman

Tags: arrays, json, api, schema

Hello there I have a API that sends dynamic responses and I want to validate the schema of that response.following is the response I am trying to validate.

```
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "CustomerName": "BeautyProductions",
  
            "Websites": {
                "storeone": {
                    "Keyone":"testvalueone",
                    "Keytwo":"testvalue two"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But the thing is the number of websites increases sometimes like following

```
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "CustomerName": "BeautyProductions",
  
            "Websites": {
                "storeone": {
                    "Keyone":"testvalueone",
                    "Keytwo":"testvalue two"
                },
                "storetwo": {
                    "Keyone":"testvaluestoretwo",
                    "Keytwo":"testvaluestoretwonow"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to validate schema as following

```
var schema = {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Data": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "CustomerName": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "Websites": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "storeone": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "Keyone": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "Keytwo": {
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  },
                  "required": [
                    "Keyone",
                    "Keytwo"
                  ]
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "storeone"
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "CustomerName",
            "Websites"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "Data"
  ]
}

var json = pm.response.json()
pm.test('shcema is valid', function(){
    pm.expect(tv4.validate(json, schema)).to.be.true;
})
```

But it fails when the number of website count is increasing. SO, I would liketo know how I can validate this?
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the "stored" field is required, but you can use the "additionalProperties". The "additionalProperties" field allows you to specify a schema for properties in the object that are not explicitly defined in the properties field.
Please try below schema if it works:

```
var schema = {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Data": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "CustomerName": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "Websites": {
              "type": "object",
              "additionalProperties": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "Keyone": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "Keytwo": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                },
                "required": [
                  "Keyone",
                  "Keytwo"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "CustomerName",
            "Websites"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "Data"
  ]
}
```